# Parsing nested JSON with GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I have JSON object as

```
{"Field1":"Value1",
 "MessageId":"12345",
 "Message":"{"Field1":"Value",
            "Field2":"Value2",   
            "Field3":["Value3"]
           }"
 }
```

I am want to deserialize the inner message into an object. To this I wrote:

```
public MessageObject deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        final JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject("Message");

        final String field1 = jsonObject.get("Field1").getAsString();
        final String field2 = jsonObject.get("Field2").getAsString();
        final String field3 = jsonObject.get("Field3").getAsArray();
...
```

However in my unit tests it errors out as invalid JSON. I can always guarantee that the inner message is a Json object.
To this I also tried escaping the message String with \\, but it still errors out as errors out as unable to cast JsonPrimitive to JsonObject for:

```
\"Message\":\"{\\\"Field1\\\":\\\"Value\\\",
            \\\"Field2\\\":\\\"Value2\\\",   
            \\\"Field3\\\":[\\\"Value3\\\"]
           }\"
```

Is there someway I can get GSON to parse the inner object as JSON as well?

Comment: How are you doing the assert in your unit test? Maybe we can throw in some ideas on how you can better test this.

Comment: Well, I am calling a method deserializeToMessageObject() on the String. Once I have it parsed I am checking if Field1,Field2,Field3 are equal to expected values, in this case Value1,Value2,Value3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class will act as POJO (Plain Old Java Object) which is like a form and Gson is going to fill it.

```
public class OurClass {
    public String Field1;
    public int MessageId;
    public Map<String, Object /* Here can be any object */> Message;
}
```

Now actually parsing.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
OurClass ourClass = null;
ourClass = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("file.json"), OurClass.class);
```

Output of `System.out.println(ourClass.Field1);`

```
Value1
```

Output of `System.out.println(ourClass.Message);`

```
{Field1=Value, Field2=Value2, Field3=[Value3]}
```

It looks bad, but this is because of your ugly (sorry) json file.
You can view more examples and guide on [this GitHub page](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md).

Answer (score 0):

You tried this, where the value of `Message` is entirely *unescaped*, aka invalid:

```
{"Field1":"Value1",
 "MessageId":"12345",
 "Message":"{"Field1":"Value",
            "Field2":"Value2",   
            "Field3":["Value3"]
           }"
 }
```

Then this, when it is *double* escaped:

```
\"Message\":\"{\\\"Field1\\\":\\\"Value\\\",
            \\\"Field2\\\":\\\"Value2\\\",   
            \\\"Field3\\\":[\\\"Value3\\\"]
           }\"
```

How about you try escaping it just *once*, **including the newlines**?

```
{"Field1": "Value1",
 "MessageId": "12345",
 "Message": "{\"Field1\":\"Value\",\n            \"Field2\":\"Value2\",   \n            \"Field3\":[\"Value3\"]\n           }"
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, I should've clarified, I had to double escape since this is being passed in a as a String literal in JUnit and everything needs to be escaped at least once.

Comment: You missed the main point. A JSON string cannot contain control characters (see [spec](http://www.json.org/)), which includes newlines, so they have to be escaped as `\n` (or `\r\n`). You didn't do that, which is why it doesn't parse.